# C++ Module in Python - Get the runtime path?

Tags: python, c++

In a regular C++ exec, I can get the full path of the exec with

```
  // Read path to executable
  char cpath[PATH_MAX];
  ssize_t count = readlink("/proc/self/exe", cpath, sizeof cpath);
```

But if I call it in a Python script, the same thing returns
`/usr/bin/python3.6`

What if i wanted the full `/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/myscript.py`

How can I access the variable?

I want the C++ module to know the actual location of the script run, or the location of its own self (.so file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same.

```
ifstream cmdline("/proc/self/cmdline");
std::string cpath;
std::getline(cmdline, cpath);
```

Comment: This combines the entire command into a single string. eg. `/home/user/.pyenv/bin/python3/home/user/myscript.py

Comment: This single string contains args delimited by zero-char.

Comment: yeap that zero-char kicked my ass for 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

The code is as following:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("given path") 
complete_path = path.absolute() 
print(complete_path)
```

Comment: Actually, what i need is a way to have a library know the location of its own .so file

Comment: I did not really get what you mean. But it is enough to know the directory and file name to get a full path.